# Why Blazor web assembly doesn't work in docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

I build a simple blazor web assembly but I am unable to run it in docker. Here is the error I am getting:

```
Attaching to client_client_1
client_1  | Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
client_1  | Possible reasons for this include:
client_1  |   * You intended to execute a .NET program:
client_1  |       The application 'client.dll' does not exist.
client_1  |   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
client_1  |       It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
client_1  |       Install a .NET SDK from:
client_1  |         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
client_client_1 exited with code 145
```

I generated a basic dotnet `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`. Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["client.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "client.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "client.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "client.dll"]
```

Finally here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  client:
    image: client
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

Comment: given your workdir, the entrypoint is executing `dotnet /app/client.dll`. is it possible that the dll is somewhere else?

Comment: ``client.dll`` is not in the directory. I have only ``web.config``, ``wwwroot`` in the ``app`` directory. After replacing ``COPY --from=publish /app/publish .`` from ``Dockerfile``  to ``COPY --from=publish /app .`` now I have ``publish`` and ``build`` folder in ``app`` directory. But when  changing the entry point to ``["dotnet", "build/client.dll"]`` I am getting ``Cannot use file stream for [/app/build/client.deps.json]: No such file or directory`` error

Comment: ok - this seems to be an issue of paths, not necessarily a problem with docker. but i have no experience with dotnet, so unfortunately i can't help much